# Following is some assembly code by VS2012, how can I write it on gcc?

Tags: c, assembly

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int a = 0 ;
    /*How can I write it on gcc*/
    __asm {
         mov a, 2 ;
         add a, 4 ;
    }
    printf ("%d\n",a );
    return 0 ;
}
```

This is some assembly code by VS2012, how can I write it on gcc?

Comment: By asking google for any one of the millions of samples and copying the style. I typed "gcc inline asm" into google and got 19,400,000 results. Perhaps you need to try a little harder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write it in gcc as:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  int a = 0 ;
  /*How can I write it on gcc*/
  __asm__ __volatile__ (
    "movl $2, %0\n\t"
    "addl $4, %0\n\t"
    :"=r"(a) /* =r(egister), =m(emory) both fine here */
  );
  printf ("%d\n",a );
  return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int a = 0 ;
    /*How can I write it on gcc*/
    asm volatile 
    (
         "mov $2, %0\n"
         "add $4, %0\n"
         : "=r"(a) /* output operand */
         : /* input operand */
         : /* clobbered operands */
    );
    printf ("%d\n",a );
    return 0 ;
}
```

Please read [GCC's extended asm syntax](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) for further information.

Comment: uhh..There's some wrong of your code..Could u give me some correct code ?

Comment: Actually `"=r"(a)` is an output operand

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out and I've fixed the answer. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

For example create another file `fun.s` and do following

```
.global my_fun #to show where program should start
     my_fun:
     push %ebp  #save stack ptr
     #function body
     pop %ebp   #recover stack ptr
 ret
```

Then simply invoke it in your main function

> int main(){
>   
>  my_fun();
>   }

Compile like this: `g++ -o prog fun.s main.cpp`